# Exception type error

Tags: haskell

I'm learning how exceptions work in Haskell.
When trying to replicate [this](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/error-handling.html#errors.exceptions.firststeps) simple example in Prelude I get:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :m Control.Exception
Prelude Control.Exception> let x = 5 `div` 0
Prelude Control.Exception> let y = 5 `div` 1
Prelude Control.Exception> print x
*** Exception: divide by zero
Prelude Control.Exception> print y
5
Prelude Control.Exception> try (print x)

<interactive>:16:1:
    No instance for (Show (IO (Either e0 ())))
      arising from a use of `print'
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
Prelude Control.Exception>
```

Why do I get the **no instance error** on `try(print x)`, when previously I got an exception?

Comment: the problem is that **GHCi** does not know the type of `e0` so you have to tell: `try (print x) :: IO (Either ArithException ())` - the reason is that at compile time there are quite a few possible instances (for the different exceptions: [see here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:Exception) - and GHCi cannot choose)

Comment: (of course you can always use `SomeException` too)

Comment: @Carsten That looks like an answer to me!

Comment: @DanielWagner done - thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is that Haskell/*GHCi* does not know the type of `e0` so you have to annotate it:

```
try (print x) :: IO (Either ArithException ())
```

the reason is that at compile time there are quite a few possible instances (for the different exceptions): [see here for a description](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:Exception) - and *GHCi* cannot choose

You can get GHCi to tell you so if you look a bit deeper into the expressions (more or less don't directly force *GHCi* to `show` it):

```
Prelude Control.Exception> e <- try (print x)

<interactive>:5:6:
    No instance for (Exception e0) arising from a use of `try'
    The type variable `e0' is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Exception NestedAtomically
        -- Defined in `Control.Exception.Base'
      instance Exception NoMethodError
        -- Defined in `Control.Exception.Base'
      instance Exception NonTermination
        -- Defined in `Control.Exception.Base'
      ...plus 7 others
    In the first argument of `GHC.GHCi.ghciStepIO ::
                                IO a_a18N -> IO a_a18N', namely
      `try (print x)'
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command:
      e <- GHC.GHCi.ghciStepIO :: IO a_a18N -> IO a_a18N (try (print x))
```

---

of course you don't have to *guess* the right exception (as **I** did with `ArithException`) - instead you can use `SomeException` to *catch* all too:

```
Prelude Control.Exception> try (print x) :: IO (Either SomeException ())
Left divide by zero
```